# egrep -- three letter words in text that begin with ‘t’ and end with 'e'

Tags: regex, grep

I tried to find a three letter words in text file  that begin with ‘t’ and end with 'e'. but when i used this it didnt work what am i doing wrong?

> egrep -owi '^t\w*e\b' && '\w{1,3}'  text.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the && feels like it could be misinterpreted by the shell.

how about:

> egrep -owi 't.e' test.txt

Comment: Thank you. so if we wanted that in a 6 letter word we would do 't....e' ?

Comment: that certainly would work.  You might appreciate your other trick of:
't.{1,4}e' for a range of ever work beginning with t, ending in e between 3 and 6 letters